# Use the Holder inequality to show that $f \ast g \in C_c(G)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $G$ be a locally compact abelian group, and let $f \in L^p(G), g \in L^q(G)$.  I'm trying to prove that $f \ast g \in C_0(G)$.  The book I'm reading (Rudin, *Analysis on Groups*) gives the following sketch of the proof:

Since $C_c(G)$ is dense in the $L^p$ spaces, there exist sequences $f_n \in L^p(G), g_n \in L^q(G)$ such that $||f - f_n||_p, ||g - g_n||_q \to 0$.  It suffices then, to show that $f_n \ast g_n$ converges to $f \ast g$ uniformly.  Since $f_n \ast g_n \in C_c(G)$ (we've already proved that $C_c(G)$ is closed under convolution), this will imply that $f_n \ast g_n \to f \ast g$ in the sup norm.  Since $C_c(G)$ is dense in $C_0(G)$, the claim will follow.

But, I don't see why $f_n \ast g_n \to f \ast g$ uniformly.  Rudin claims that this follows from the Holder inequality, but I'm having trouble making it work.

Comment: Is $\frac 1p + \frac 1q = 1$?

Comment: Yes, it is.  Most certainly (adding characters because of the minimum length.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure the following works. Please double check and let me know if I am wrong.

---

We have, for $x \in G$,
\begin{align}
|f_n*g_n(x)-f*g(x)| & = |f_n*g_n(x) - f*g_n(x) + f*g_n(x) - f*g(x)| \leq \\
& \leq |f_n*g_n(x) - f*g_n(x)| + |f*g_n(x) - f*g(x)| \leq \\
&  \leq|(f_n - f)*g_n(x)| + |f*(g_n-g)(x)| \leq \\
& \leq \|f_n-f\|_p\|g_n\|_q + \|f\|_p\|g_n-g\|_q \leq \\
& \leq M\|f_n-f\|_p + \|f\|_p\|g_n-g\|_q \to 0.
\end{align}

where we used the fact that $g_n$ is bounded in $L^q$ (since it is convergent) and that $f_n \to f$ in $L^p$ and $g_n \to q$ in $L^q$.
Since the final line goes to zero uniformly in $x$ the convergence is uniform. Moreover we have used the fact that $L^p$ norm is invariant under translation.

Comment: You're right.  I figured out this answer right after I posted the question :)